# Why are there so many duplicates of "explorer.exe" running?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, troubleshooting, task-manager

In my Windows 7 task manager, there are 16 instances of explorer.exe running. Where is this coming from?

I thought perhaps I had inadvertently enabled the option of Windows replicating an instance for every folder/window opened. But this isn't enabled. Nor do any further explorer's appear when I open new explorer (My Computer) windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever the cause, it's generally not good or useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this useful:
[multiple instances of explorer.exe running in task manager (currently 7)](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/there-are-multiple-instances-of-explorerexe/d4f28787-6208-4756-aa9d-96f7a6d34b7e)

In a nutshell one possible cause suggested in the above referenced link is that calling **expolorer.exe** (through shurtcut/command line and so on) with any argument other then default directory from **Libraries** will cause explorer task to hang when you close it.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the task manager, note the number of **explorer.exe** processes you have runnuing
2. Open command line
3. Run the following:  **explorer.exe C:\**  - will result in a explorer window opened at **C:\**
4. Close the explorer window that opened as a result of step 3.
5. You should now note that you have another **explorer.exe** process still hanging in the background on top of the ones you already had.

On my computer (Win7 x64) the above steps resulted in a hanging **explorer.exe** process consuming about 12MB of memory each time.

BTW just for reference, to see a proper flow just call **explorer.exe** from the command line with no arguments.